# Ansible - create a list of unused disks

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create a list of unused disks from gather facts

```
-

           key | search ("sd")

     with_dict: "{{ ansible_devices }}"
```

But its only displaying one disk, like if the server have two unused disks sdb and sdc , its only displaying sdb. How can I modify my code to include all unused disks.

Answer (score 2):

the way you have it, `set_fact` gets equal to the "current" item from the iteration, probably this is why you see only 1 disk in the final result. You need to set the `disks` as a list of elements and append to that list the current `item.key`. you can use this syntax:

```
set_fact:
   disks: "{{ disks|default([]) + ['/dev/{{item.key}}'] }}"
```

to understand how many results you have in the loops of the `with_dict` clause, you can try a `debug` task:

```
- name: Print disk result

     debug:
        msg: "/dev/{{item.key}}"

     when:
     - not item.value.partitions
     - not item.value.holders
     - not item.value.links.ids
     - item.key | search ("sd")

     with_dict: "{{ ansible_devices }}"
```

(indentation may need fixes, i just copied from your code)

hope it helps

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, its showing result as below:
=> {
    "disks": [
        "/dev/sdc",
        "/dev/{{item.key}}"
    ]

Comment: thats pretty weird output... can you post how the `ansible_devices` variable looks like in your setup? you can edit your question and add this info.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply, I used the mentioned code for printing the disk result, it was displaying multiple disks, but when I used set_fact, and the msg to display the variable, its showing like this:-

```json
"disks": [
        "/dev/sdc",
        "/dev/{{item.key}}"
    ]
```

```yaml
   - name: Print disk result
     set_fact:
        disks: "{{ disks|default([]) + ['/dev/{{item.key}}'] }}"
     when:
     - not item.value.partitions
     - not item.value.holders
     - not item.value.links.ids
     - item.key | search ("sd")
     with_dict: "{{ ansible_devices }}"

   - debug: var=disks
```

Comment: kindly explain your answer. It will help future reader as well.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is ever looking for the answer, this works for me:

```
- name: Print disk result
  set_fact:
    disks: "{{ disks|default([]) + ['/dev/' + item.key] }}"
  when:
  - not item.value.partitions
  - not item.value.holders
  - not item.value.links.ids
  - item.key | regex_search ("sd")
  with_dict: "{{ ansible_devices }}"

- name: debug
  debug:
    msg: "{{disks}}"
```

It returns:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "/dev/sdb"
    ]
}
```